# MVC и MVP на примере php проектов

Tags: php, mvc, mvp

Нашёл вот такое сравнение в картинках для этих двух шаблонов:

[image: диаграмма взаимодействия]

Но я не понимаю их. По моему, по крайней мере в MVC всё происходит так:
user отправляет запрос на сервер -> его обрабатываем приложение и выбирает контроллер -> контролер лезет в модель -> модель возвращает данные -> контроллер отдаёт вьюху. Почему на первой картинке нарисовано что вьюха сама пользователю прилетает? Это просто html файл, он не может сам себя echo'нуть.

Но если даже принять картинку на веру, то получается разница между патернами в том, что mvc - это то, что я описал, a mvp это view, который работает на ajax по схеме, которую я описал. 
В mvc отдаётся новая страница, в mvp прилетает кусок кода и меняет какой нибудь div.

Comment: Потому что есть вариации MVC - с активной и пассивной моделью + еще несколько. Классической считается с "активной моделью (модель сама уведомляет представления". Она же у вас на картинке. В вебе же больше подходит "пассивная модель (контроллер разруливает между моделью и представлением)"

Comment: пожалуйста конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: так что же такое MVP? На примере веба с php можно объяснить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Оригинал тут](https://habr.com/post/215605/)

**Model-View-Presenter**

Данный подход позволяет создавать абстракцию представления. Для этого необходимо выделить интерфейс представления с определенным набором свойств и методов. Presenter, в свою очередь, получает ссылку на реализацию интерфейса, подписывается на события представления и по запросу изменяет модель.
Если у вас наблюдается:

- Двухсторонняя коммуникация с представлением;
- Представление (view) взаимодействует напрямую с представителем (Presenter), путем вызова соответствующих функций или событий экземпляра представителя;
- Представитель (presenter) взаимодействует с представлением (view) путем использования специального интерфейса, реализованного представлением;

Можно считать, что у вас реализуется шаблон MVP.

Разница между MVC и MVP заключается в том, что представление (View) полностью пассивное и ничего не знает о модели. Напротив в MVC представление (View) *не пассивно* и имеет представление о модели.

В "правильном" MVP, класс View (если он есть) также **не должен** реализовывать конструктор.

Типичная реализация шаблона MVP содержит:

1. Уровень доступа к данным (DataMappers, ORM и т.д.)
2. Бизнес-логика (например, проверка и вычисления)
3. Пассивный класс представления (например шаблонизатор или что-то подобное, но лучше если это будет класс)
4. Представитель (presenter) который соединяет модель и представление (View)

Маленький пример ([взял отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530023/does-php-supports-mvp-pattern/15155046))

```
class Model
{
   public function getSomeStuff()
   {
       return array('foo' => 'bar');
   }
}

class View
{
   public function render($path, array $vars = array())
   {
      ob_start();
      extract($vars);
      require($path);
      return ob_get_clean();
   }
}

class Presenter
{ 
     private $model;
     private $view;

     public function __construct(Model $model, View $view)
     {
         $this->model = $model;
         $this->view = $view; 
     }

     public function indexAction()
     {
        $data = $this->model->getSomeStuff();  
        // Значениея установлены и теперь формируем HTML в виде строки
        return $this->view->render('path/to/template.phtml', $data);
     }
}
```

template.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php foreach($vars as $key => $value): ?>
      <p><?php echo $key; ?> : <?php echo $value; ?></p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Использование

```
$model = new Model();
$view = new View();
$presenter = new Presenter($service, $view);
echo $presenter->indexAction();
```

Это очень упрощённый пример, раскрывающий суть шаблона.

Comment: Часть текста Вашего ответа совпадает с содержимым [**статьи на Хабрахабре 2014 года**](https://habr.com/post/215605/). Пожалуйста, [**добавьте ссылку на оригинал либо перепишите текст своими словами**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1080/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: Спасобо, @СашаЧерных. добавил ссылки на оригиналы.